What is difference between 'docker compose up --watch' and 'docker compose watch'?
Just like title says.
What is difference between
docker compose up --watch
and
docker compose watch?
I used both, and it seems like there is no big difference on how docker compose reacts according to file change. I have noticed that logs printed on screen is shown for docker compose up --watch but not for docker compose watch.

Actually, docker compose up --watch this commands will run the services which defined in docker-compose.yml file and flag --watch enable watching for file changes.
In the other hand, docker compose watch is only watch for changes in the source code and rebuild or restart containers when changes are detected. The focus point is, this command watching changes without initially starting the services like up does.
If you already up your services you can only run command watch, but if you're services is not yet installed you can using compose up with flag --watch to see the files changes.
I hope this simple answer can help you. :)

So, if a container is not running and I use docker compose watch, it will not start my containers?

@PaulKim Yes it's exact, docker compose watch do not start any container.
